# Append Cloned Div to right side of original element, slide left, then remove original

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am creating an ajax slider with only the one "slide" thats data reloads during slide.

My current method is to animate the absolute positioned element out of parent viewport, jump to right hand side of viewport and slide back in. This gives the illusion of the element sliding.

I have an idea of cloning the slide and appending it to the right hand side of the original element, animating left so clone is in view and the removing the original element.

I have got as far as creating the clone and removing original but am unsure of how to append the clone to the right hand side of original element. Any thoughts on how to do this would be appreciated.

### HTML STRUCTURE

```
<!-- Relative Parent -->
<div id="gameBoxWrap">

    <!-- The Slide -->
    <div class="gameBox">

        <div class="gameBoxContent">
            <!-- Have removed content for readability -->
        </div>

    </div>  
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#gameBoxWrap {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px; 
}

.gameBox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 938px;
  height: 690px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

### JS

```
//
// CREATES A CLONE OF ELEMENT - I am trying to append the clone to the right hand side of the original element

var $el = $('.gameBox');
$el.clone(true).appendTo('#gameBoxWrap');

//     The current settings below are as follows:
//
//      1. Slide Element out of relative parent viewport
//      2. Jump Element to right hand edge of parent viewport
//      3. Slide Element to orignal position
//
//
//      My thought pattern for ideal process
//
//      1. Wait for clone to be appended on right hand side
//      2. Slide left so Original Element is out of viewport
//      3. Remove Orginal Element

var settings = 
[
    [     {"left": "-950px"},{duration: 400,complete: function() {$(this).css("left", window.innerWidth + $(this).width());}}     ],
    [     {"left": "1px"}, {duration: 400}    ]
];

$(".gameBox").queue("_fx", $.map(settings, function(options, i) {
  return function(next) {
    return $(this).animate.apply($(this), options).promise().then(next);
  };
})).dequeue("_fx");


// REMOVES ORIGINAL ELEMENT
$el.remove();
```

Comment: well that is the correct positioning, if you could help me integrate this into my script so clone is positioned to right or original I should be able to work out the slide

Comment: this is pretty much perfect, I just need to tailor it so that the original div moves left with the new one like a normal slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your javascript section with the following code. Here's the breakdown

1. Get the box, assign it to a variable for future use.
2. Clone it, assign that to a variable for future use.
3. Append the the clone hidden
4. Set the left value to be off canvas
5. Set the animation of the clone
6. Show the clone
7. Set the animation of the original
8. Set the left value of the original to be off canvas
9. After the animation has finished, remove the original

```js
var el = $('.gameBox');
var elNew = el.clone(true);
$('#gameBoxWrap').append(elNew.hide());
elNew.css('left', '100%');
elNew.show();
el.css('transition', 'left 1s ease-in-out');
el.css('left','-100%');
elNew.css('transition', 'left 1s ease-in-out');
elNew.css('left','0px');
window.setTimeout(function(){
    el.remove();
},1000);
```

Comment: This is great! I am trying to fine tune the timing of the slides so that the ajax content is loaded when both slides are out of view. I'm sure I can work with your answer but any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Should I edit my answer with entire plugin script or would you like to create a chat room?